# How to implement transition from one html page to another in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I've connected the database to my login and registration pages, and now I can't figure out how to connect the rest of the pages.
Now it gives me an error

```
werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'gyrnal'. Did you mean 'login' instead?
```

Why did my page `glavnai` become `login`?
And how can I make it so that I can use the navigation menu from any page?

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('avtoriz.html')

@app.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template('registr.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_post():
    # Output message if something goes wrong...
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        # Create variables for easy access
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        # Retrieve the hashed password

        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM polzovatel WHERE username = %s AND password = %s', (username, password,))
        # Fetch one record and return the result
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            # Create session data, we can access this data in other routes
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['id'] = account['id']
            session['username'] = account['username']
            # Redirect to home page
            return redirect(url_for('glavnai'))
        else:
            # Account doesnt exist or username/password incorrect
            msg = 'Неверный логин или пароль'

    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_post():
    # Output message if something goes wrong...
    msg = ''
    # Check if "username", "password" and "email" POST requests exist (user submitted form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' and 'number' in request.form:
        # Create variables for easy access
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
        number = request.form['number']
        # Check if account exists using MySQL
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM polzovatel WHERE username = %s', (username,))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        # If account exists show error and validation checks
        if account:
            msg = 'Аккаунт уже существует'
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
            msg = 'Неверный формат почты'
        elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', username):
            msg = 'Логин может иметь только буквы и цыфры'
        elif not username or not password or not email:
            msg = 'Пожалуйста, заполните все формы'
        else:
            # Account doesn't exist, and the form data is valid, so insert the new account into the accounts table
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO polzovatel VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (username, password, email, number,))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            msg = 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались!'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # Form is empty... (no POST data)
        msg = 'Пожалуйста, заполните форму полностью'
    # Show registration form with message (if any)
    return render_template('registr.html', msg=msg)

@app.route('/glavnai')
def glavnai():
    return render_template('glavnai.html')

@app.route('/gyrnal')
def gyrnal():
    return render_template('gyrnal.html')

@app.route('/korzina')
def korzina():
    return render_template('korzina.html')

@app.route('/magazin')
def magazin():
    return render_template('magazin.html')
```

```
        <form action="{{ url_for('glavnai') }}">
        <button id="menu" class="text_menu">Главная</button></form>
        <form action="{{ url_for('gyrnal') }}">
        <button id="menu" class="text_menu">Журнал</button></form>
```

I tried to write other tags (, onclick) , but the maximum that worked was the transition to the "Главная" button on the authorization page, because for some reason the main page has the address "login"